# Svelte withTypescript using Parcel

Tags: typescript, parcel, svelte

I have seen that one can use rollup to allow for Svelte components written in typescript, but is it possible to do the same with Parcel? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. I managed to figure it out. I made a working example on [Github](https://github.com/dafn/svelte-typescript-parcel)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the example.
I am wondering if it's possible to use a framework to unit test the components created in that structure.